# Jenkins resource root URL not serving any content

Tags: jenkins, content-security-policy

I have configured a correct resource root URL in my Jenkins.
Jenkins is available internally under https://jenkins-master-test.ads.vhv.de/
Static content is to be served under https://jenkins-master-doc-test.ads.vhv.de/

Config validation finds the new URL and it looks like everything is fine.
But no content is server over the Resource root URL. It is documented that the workspce files wil be serverd with the new URL, but they are not.

Any Idea if something is missing?